# Does Windows Azure support wcf duplex?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, duplex

I'm implementing an WCF application (service) on Windows Azure to notify to my client (**a WPF application, not Silverlight**)
I have tried many ways for authentication connection to Windows Azure, such as:

- Active Directory Azure: Connect success to Azure with authetication but IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding does not support Duplex.
- WsDualHttpBinding: cannot connect with Azure because this binding does not authenticated .
- ServiceCredentials :authentication mode:Windows, Federation,UsernamePassword :cannot connect with Azure because this binding does not authenticated .

, I have researched this problem more than 3 months but all ways couldn't successful.

I want to know, **does Windows Azure support wcf duplex**?

Comment: I do not know about the requirements; but have you considered using SignalR if you are planning to use WCF to support push messages?

Comment: Also consider `NetHttpBinding` which is the new WebSockets binding. Again in the same vein as daryal's answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows Azure"?  Cloud Services, Web Sites, Virtual Machines?